# Values comparison

Tags: javascript

```
[4] === 4 // is: false
[4] == 4 // is: true

'0' == 0 // is: true
'0' === 0 // is: false
```

Can anyone give the exact reason for this?Also what exactly does strict equality operator do or need for comparision?I learned that *type* and *value* should be same for strict(===) operator.Is this what strict equality operator checks .If yes,than how equl to operator works?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

- `==` Compare values
- `===` Compare values *and* type

### For example

```
[4] //turns into "4" when comparing
"4" == 4 //They are the same

"4" === 4 //The values are the same, but not the type
```

Reference: http://es5.github.io/#x11.9.4

> https://i.stack.imgur.com/q13LO.png

Comment: how can "4" be equal to 4 .One is string and one is number.

Comment: @Maizere - `==` [does not care its type](http://es5.github.io/#x11.9.3).

Comment: @Maizere Welcome to javascript

Comment: @Derek 朕會功夫 did u mean it only takes care of values

Comment: @Maizere - Actually, it will turn your String into a Number when comparing a String to a Number as it stated in [the spec](http://es5.github.io/#x11.9.3). So the type is not a factor when using `==`.

Comment: @badZoke ur username should be goodZoke

Comment: @Maizere - More mind-blown: `[4] == [4] //false`

Comment: @Derek 朕會功夫 oh no.How can this be false again?i m having a severe pain in my head now

Comment: @Maizere In that case, the comparison is of references. Since each `[4]` is a `new Array()`, they aren't the *same*; only *similar*, which `==` doesn't check for.

Comment: @ Jonathan Lonowski To quote Douglas Crockford's excellent JavaScript: The Good Parts,

 evil twins(==) do the right thing when the operands are of the same type, but if they are of different types, they attempt to coerce the values.this means [4]==[4] should be equal becoz both are of same type

Comment: @ Derek 朕會功夫  To quote Douglas Crockford's excellent JavaScript: The Good Parts, evil twins(==) do the right thing when the operands are of the same type, but if they are of different types, they attempt to coerce the values.this means [4]==[4] should be equal becoz both are of same type

Comment: @Maizere - According to the spec, when comparing an Array to another Array, unless they have the same reference, it will always return `false`.

Comment: @Derek朕會功夫 Do this apply only in case of an array or it applies for variables too?

Comment: @Maizere - If you are comparing variables referring to the same Array, it would return `true`: `var a=b=[4]; a === b //true`

Comment: @Maizere It applies to any 2 `Object`s (non-primitives) -- `new String()` vs. `""`; `new Number()` vs. `0`; as well as `Object`, `Array`, `RegExp`, `Function`, etc. In comparing 2 `Object`s, you're comparing references, so they must be references to the exact same `Object` to be equal. So, `var a = [], b = a; a == b;` vs. `[] == [];`

Comment: @ Derek 朕會功夫 i mean are this false like say:x=10;y=10 (x==y)?

Comment: @Maizere - It will return `true`. Why would it false anyway?

Comment: @ Derek 朕會功夫 false == 'false' //false why?since false should be coerced to string and the output should be true

Comment: @Maizere - No, [the spec](http://es5.github.io/#x11.9.4) says if the left hand side is Boolean, then it will be changed into a Number. `false == 0 //true` ([whisper]JavaScript sucks![whisper])

Answer (score 1):

The `===` operator also compares the `type` of the object.

So, in `[4] === 4`

[4] is an array, but 4 is a number, so that evaluates to false.

And in `'0' === 0`

'0' is a string, but 0 is a number, so that evaluates to false.

Comment: what about equal(==) to operator

Comment: the `==` compares only the value. Not the type.

Answer (score 0):

The === operator compares both type and value, making it a stricter check.
The == operator performs a less strict value based checked. It will in some cases consider values of different types "equal" Such examples are 0 vs '' or 0 vs "0"

The == operator will see 0 and '' as equal whereas the === operator will not treat them as equal since they are of different types.